# StreamWriter generates 0 byte file

Tags: c#, io, windows-ce

I have the following logics below that get called once every 20 minutes via a Timer, it serializes the content of the object into a file path, The filePath i see is \hard disk\logs\applicationstate.xml , please note I confirm this is a valid path..

It works most of the time but every now and then I get the `System.IO.IOeException` on the line `this.StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath);` with the following stack stack trace:

> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)\r\n    at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean useAsync, String
>   msgPath)\r\n    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)\r\n    at
>   System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append)\r\n
>   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding
>   encoding, Int32 bufferSize)\r\n    at
>   System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path)\r\n    at
>   Shs.ScanPanel.CA.DataManager.DataManagercr.CopyData(Object data)\r\n
>   at System.Threading.Timer.ring()\r\n"

When it happens I see \hard disk\logs\applicationstate.xml exists but it has 0 byte.

So my question is, could the StreamWriter cause this 0 byte file to be generated in the first place? I read up on the IOException under StreamWriter on MSDN and it says the following

**IOException

path includes an incorrect or invalid syntax for file name, directory name, or volume label syntax.**

This confused me, is it because it tries to open a stream writer to a 0 byte file? could this 0 byte generated in the last time this code runs where a null object was being serialized into the file? if so why didn't I see that exception in Visual Studio?

```
            if (filePath != string.Empty)
            {
                if (this.StateObject == null)
                {
                    this.StateObject = new State();
                }
                    //Do something to my StateObject object

                    this.StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath);
                    this.Serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(State));

                    this.Serializer.Serialize(this.StreamWriter, this.StateObject);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (this.log != null)
                    {
                        this.log.Write(LogLevel.Error, this.componentName, "CopyData : Unable to initilize State Object");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.log != null)
                {
                    this.log.Write(LogLevel.Error, this.componentName, "CopyData : Error while retrieving Current working directory");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (this.log != null)
            {
                this.log.Write(ex, this.componentName);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (this.StreamWriter != null)
            {
                this.StreamWriter.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You didnt close your stream...

Comment: Is there a Message in the IOException? AFAIK this exception can be raised for different types of error.

Comment: You'll need to document the specific error better.  You can get an error code from Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()

Comment: BugFinder, I thought my  this.StreamWriter.Close(); in the Finally clause will close it.

Comment: ShellShock, aside from the stack trace when I look at the Inner Exception it just says "Could not evaluate expression"

Comment: OK, I missed that it had scrolled off the bottom. :( that would have given you the same problem, especially if its already open being written to

Comment: How fast is your timer?  Is it possible that the timer callback is invoked again while the file is being written to (re-entrant, callback is invoked again before the last one finished)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wrote up a little program and I confirmed that the line that makes the file to have 0 byte is right at the  this.StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath);

But what really boggle my mind is that it successfully wipe out the file so that new data can be serialized into it but yet at the same time it throws exception.  I'm thinking this is a lower layer of the StreamWriter api or it could be something with the flash drive.... after all I'm running this program on WINDOW CE

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using **this.StreamWriter.Flush()** to make sure all the contents are written.

However you exception appears to be complaining that the path is incorrect.

Edit: Opps I missed the WinCE tag